# User map scrolling

Tags: javascript, p5.js

Let's say that I have a 2d plane. A 2d plane that is 10000 * 10000 units.

Now this plane has many objects scattered around it. Let's say these objects are rectangles. I want to be able to show the user only 500 * 500 area of any part of the map with the rectangles included.

My question is: How do I show part of an area of a map to the user?

If you don't understand the question I can show you what I mean in the image below:

[image: This is the image]

This code is what I have tried so far:

```
var socket = io("localhost:8000");
var data = {};
var init = false;
var screenPos = {
    x:0,y:0
};
var setup = function(){
    createCanvas(500,500);
    background(255);
    socket.on("init",function(d){ // This just gets the position of the building relative to the 10000 * 10000 square
        data = d;
        screenPos = {
            x: data.building.x - width/2, // building.x - screenwidth/2 this line is supposed to theoretically center the drawing on the rectangle :|
            y: data.building.y - height/2 //building.y - screenheight/2
        };
        loop();
    })
    socket.on("update",function(d){
        data = d;
    });
noLoop();
};

var draw = function(){
    rect(data.building.x,data.building.y,50,50); // In this example, the rectangle is the building
};
```

The rectangle can be anywhere from 0,0 to 10000,10000.
If you need me to elaborate further do NOT be afraid to ask for more information.

Assume data coming from the server is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the built-in `camera()` function:

```js
function setup(){
  createCanvas(100, 100);
}
function draw(){
  background(0);
 camera(mouseX, mouseY);
fill(255, 0, 0);
 rect(50, 50, 50, 50);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/processing/p5.js/releases/download/0.5.4/p5.js"></script>
<p>Mouse over this:</p>
```

More info can be found in [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/camera).

Comment: I'll check this function out. I'll get back to you on this.

Comment: Thank you so much, It does exactly what I wanted it to do :D

Comment: if I wanted to do what this does but with a different canvas size but still have the user only view 500 * 500, how would I do it?

Comment: @ahitt6345 If you only want the user to see `500x500`, then wouldn't you just use a canvas of `500x500`? Then you could just use the `camera()` function to set the view. If you're trying to do something else, then please post a [mcve] in a new question and we'll go from there.